# Apple IOKit.framework use on iOS

Tags: ios

How to add IOKit in iOS Project ?

I added but encounter an error

[Please Look Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLDAi.png)

What should i do ?

Comment: You fill need to link the `IOKit.framework`, which is not available in the public SDK. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/iokit-an-introduction/) on how to grab this private framework. Be aware that using this framework wil not make it possible to submit your app to the app store.

Comment: ok,thanks for answer .i looked the your sended link.but i haven't  libIOKit.dylib.[link](http://i.hizliresim.com/OMDJrn.png) .What should i do ?